# How to sort an ArrayList of type <Entry<Character, Integer>>?

Tags: java, arraylist, comparator

I had a HashMap called map which stored Characters as the key and Integers as the value which I then stored into an ArrayList called entries using the following code:

```
Set<Entry<Character, Integer>> s = map.entrySet();
ArrayList<Entry<Character, Integer>> entries = new ArrayList<>(s);
```

Now I am trying to sort these entries based on the Integer value, not the key. I tried to use a lambda expression to implement the Comparator interface, but it is not working. This is my code:

```
Collections.sort(sortedEntries, (sortedEntries.get(0), sortedEntries.get(1)) -> { 
    sortedEntries.get(0).getValue().compareTo(sortedEntries.get(1).getValue())
});
```

These are the errors I get:

> Multiple markers at this line
>
> - Syntax error, insert ")" to complete Expression
> - The method sort(List, Comparator) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList>, Map.Entry, Map.Entry)
> - Syntax error on token "->", ; expected

Comment: The expression (x,y)->(something) is not dependent on anything before it. It should not refer to `sortedEntries`. The names of the variables are there only so that you can use them in the body of the lambda expressions, and they type is whatever the comparator expects.

Comment: Why are you using lambdas if you don't understand them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could sort the list by the values this way:

```
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(Entry::getValue));
```

Comment: Thanks! This solution worked great. Just wondering out of curiosity how would I sort it in descending order?

Comment: There are a few handy methods in the `Comparator` interface. There is a method `reversed` to get a `Comparator ` in reverse order. To sort the list by the inverse order of the Entry values, you can use: `list.sort(Comparator.comparing(Entry<Character, Integer>::getValue).reversed());`

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the entities using Java Stream API like this:

```
Set<Entry<Character, Integer>> s = map.entrySet();
List<Entry<Character, Integer>>  sortedEntries = s.stream()
            .sorted((a, b)-> Integer.compare(a.getValue(), b.getValue()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: The result is not going to be sorted if you put it into a `Set`. This should go into a list (or a sorted set).

Answer (score 0):

### This is strictly as per your code pls see

```
Collections.sort(sortedEntries, (Entry<Character,Integer> o1, Entry<Character,Integer> o2)-> {return o1.getValue().compareTo(o2.getValue());});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing special about the map, the list, or the type you're trying to sort. You sort such a list the same way you sort any List whose elements are of a type that doesn't implement Comparable - by using a Comparator, like you're attempting to do. So you're on the right track.

Perhaps if you aren't comfortable with lambda expressions, try implementing the Comparator interface instead. The type system will force you to "do it right", rather than relying on you to get it right so it can infer the types for you.

(I'm using the entry's key here, but you can just as well use the value)

```
public class EntryKeyComparator implements Comparator<Entry<Character,Integer>> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Entry<Character,Integer> a, Entry<Character,Integer> b) {
        return a.getKey().compareTo(b.getKey());
    }
}
```

Now, if you really want to use lambda expressions, you need only look at the `compare` method in this implementation. The lambda expression must take two parameters, `a` and `b`, and it must return an int. Thus, you'd get something like:

```
Collections.sort(list, (a, b) -> a.getKey().compareTo(b.getKey()));
```

But since you're already in the Java 8 world, you might as well use the static [`comparing()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-) method on the Comparator class. It takes as argument a `Function` that extracts the key you want to use to compare the elements by. In my examples, I've compared the entries by their keys via the `getKey()`. We can reference this method with the `::` operator, so you end up with an expression like this (using the new [`sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-) method on the List interface):

```
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(Entry::getKey));
```